# Display cells of tableview gradually using autolayout?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I have a tableview inside my UIViewController to display comments. The height of this tableview depends on the number and the size of comments. The cells are dynamic.

I use autolayout, so my tableview has a height constraint. I set this constraint programmatically :

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

    self.heightCommentsTableView.constant = self.commentsTableView.contentSize.height + 50 

}
```

It works if I display all the comments at once.

BUT, I would like display the comments 5 per 5, using this method : [load more for UITableView in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27079253/load-more-for-uitableview-in-swift) because of performance issue to display my view
(all my comments are loaded before pushing the view)

I noticed when I set my constraint, it calls cellForRowAtIndexPath **for all the comments**, not only the first 5.

I don't know how to do.

EDIT

```
var allCommentsArray: NSMutableArray = []
var elements: NSMutableArray = []
var range = 5
var currentPage = 0
var nextpage = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    allCommentsArray = NSMutableArray(array: comments)
    elements.addObjectsFromArray(allCommentsArray.subarrayWithRange(NSMakeRange(0, range)))
}

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {      
    return comments.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    self.nextpage = self.elements.count - 5

    if indexPath.row == nextpage {
           self.currentPage++
           self.nextpage = self.elements.count - 5
           self.elements.addObjectsFromArray(self.allCommentsArray.subarrayWithRange(NSMakeRange(self.currentPage, self.range)))

           tableView.reloadData()
    }
}


 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CommentCustomTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CommentCustomTableViewCell
     self.configureCell(cell, atIndexPath: indexPath)

     return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The table view will call `tableView(_:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)` for every visible cell it is about to create, the amount of it will determine based on how many sections and how many cells in each section.  You let the table vie know these amounts by implementing the `tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)` and `numberOfSectionsInTableView(_:)` methods of `UITableViewDataSource`.  So, if you want to control how many cells could possibly be created and visible at a given time, you'd have to manage that state in your data source by adding and removing according to whatever logic you desire.  In the  answer that you linked, you can see that he is called `elements.addObjectsFromArray` to progressively add more elements in batches.