# UITableView load more when scrolling to bottom

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I would like to load more data and create additional cells when the user scrolls to the bottom of the table. I'm using JSON data and MySql.

```
func dataJsonFromURL(url:String)->NSArray
{
    if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: url)!) {
        return ((try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: [])) as! NSArray)
    }
    else{
        return data
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("NCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell22

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor .clearColor()

    let mindata = (data[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary)
}
```

Answer (score 62):

you have to use this method

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
            let lastElement = dataSource.count - 1
            if indexPath.row == lastElement {
                // handle your logic here to get more items, add it to dataSource and reload tableview
                }    
        }
```

Comment: i really like your idea and it's working for me. But when the last product of my query comes and its officially the last one, with your code it's still trying to bring data and the table view is flickering. Any idea of how to stop it when it brought the last item?

Comment: @KwnstantinosNatsios very simple. Just need to add another flag to know it can load more or not.  if can still load more => do my logic. if not => ignore it.

Comment: This flag could be the total count of items, but i thought of it later :D

Comment: how to handle more ?

Comment: what do you mean @SaeedRahmatolahi ?

Comment: I mean how to handle jsons to load more?

Comment: could u tell me how to load tableview when scrolling to bottom and then only image will load on tableview swift @RobertTuanVu

Comment: @DilipTiwari I dont understand what you mean, can you pls explain more?

Comment: **I m getting error:** Use of unresolved identifier **'dataSource'**

Comment: For swift 4+
*dataSource* is data array

`func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let lastElement = dataSource.count - 1
        
        if indexPath.row == lastElement {
            // handle your logic here to get more items, add it to dataSource and reload tableview
        }
    }`

Answer (score 22):

**Xcode 8, Swift 3**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let lastElement = dataSource.count - 1
    if !loadingData && indexPath.row == lastElement {
        indicator.startAnimating()
        loadingData = true
        loadMoreData()
    }
}
```

Comment: the swift doesn't let me to run  the app successfully because of the loadingData
loadMoreData it shows the error "use of unresolved identifier"

Comment: @Saeed Rahmatolahi check the cell identifiers are properly assigned and used in UITableview

Comment: could you edit this codes please? I have some texts in my tableview cells that they will get by json

Comment: **I m getting error:** Use of unresolved identifier **'dataSource'**

Comment: @AnupGupta dataSource is nothing but you array of data were the table view get its values

Comment: LoadingData is a boolean flag they created to keep track of when it is loading or not. If you do not have this variable it is an "unresolved identifier"

Comment: In this case, where would you set loadingData back to false so that willDisplay does not repeatedly run?

Comment: @LukeIrvin you can set loadingData = false once the api call is finish

Answer (score 6):

i used this method and it's works for me

```
 func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let offsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    let contentHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height

    if offsetY > contentHeight - scrollView.frame.size.height {


        loadMoreDataFromServer()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Assalamaleikum dear. Why this code not work in iPhone 5s: scrollView.contentOffset.y == scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height?

Answer (score 1):

Its Called pagination to tableview.
Pagination is used to show large data on a table in an effective way.
[Here's](https://easyiostechno.wordpress.com/2014/11/14/pagination-of-table-views/) you can get nice tutorial for objective-c
and for swift look at this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27079253/load-more-for-uitableview-in-swift).

And you can download example in swift from [Here](https://github.com/Abizern/PartialTable).

Comment: i tried but not work on my code see up anyone can help me modify it

Comment: i need step by step ;(

Answer (score 1):

You need one very handy delegate method:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell , forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

}
```

This method gives your the current displayed row. Use the indexPath it provides to determine when you are nearing the bottom of the table. Then get more JSON and reload the table.

Answer (score -9):

Use this library.
https://github.com/samvermette/SVPullToRefresh

This will full fill your requirements.
You just need to change page number or timestamp every time, when new web-service will be called.

Comment: you can use Mix and Match, follow this article https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Comment: or if you are using cocoaPods, you can use directly without mix and match by just import statement on top of your viewcontroller.swift file.

Comment: anyone here i need this plz

Comment: @osamamakki pull to load more is very easy. no need to use lib. you can check my answer above