# Scroll on Demand keeps calling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, pagination

I am trying to implement scroll on demand call. Until I scroll at the bottom of the screen, it never calls `doPaging()` method which is good and then downloads another batch of dataset( 20 more items). However when it reaches at the bottom of screen first time and keeps calling even small scroll to the bottom.

I wonder what I am missing in the following implementation.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{   
    if indexPath.row == self.products.count - 1 && !isWating {
        isWating = true
        self.pageNumber += 1
        self.doPaging()
    }
}

func doPaging() 
{
    fetchProducts(page: pageNumber , completion: { success in
        if let products = success as? Products
        {
           // keeps calling
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.products.append(contentsOf:products)
                self.isWating = false;
                self.productTableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: `willDisplay` must not have side effects. Tweak the display of the cell if needed and never anything else.

Comment: could you please elaborate?

Comment: The `willDisplay` method has only one purpose. From the docs: "*A table view sends this message to its delegate just before it uses cell to draw a row, thereby permitting the delegate to customize the cell object before it is displayed."*. Don't use this for anything else (such as modifying the table view's data source or reloading the table).

Comment: I don't see the relationship between products.count and pageNumber.

Comment: @rmaddy, which delegate method needs to be used for this purpose then?

Comment: Look at the UIScrollViewDelegate protocol.

Comment: many people are using that delegate method https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588837/uitableview-load-more-when-scrolling-to-bottom

Comment: This site is loaded with plenty of bad practice example code. Just because there is an answer using `willDisplay` doesn't mean it is the proper solution.

Comment: I think you should debug and check to get idea. As per me your code is proper.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method. This will work surely

```
func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    //Bottom Refresh
    if ((scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.frame.size.height) >= scrollView.contentSize.height) {
        if !isWating {
            isWating = true
            self.doPaging()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is checking for a negative y offset. That happens when you pull down while scrolled all the way to the top, similar to a pull-to-refresh.