# Swift: Handling multiple API requests

Tags: ios, swift, api

I'm currently implementing an App which has a collectionView. The cells in the collection view are filled via an API-request. The requests are to the same API but with different locations. So for example for the first cell I'm calling: "google.de/GamesInItaly" and for the second cell: "google/GamesInGermany". While I'm scrolling down the collectionView the appearing cells should also make an API-request that has different countries.

The Problem I'm facing is, that I don't know how to handle the different API calls.
I managed to make one API-request and fill every cell with the same data, but I want different data for every cell.

My code looks like this:

**CollectionView:**

Call with from collectionView:

```
func fetchMatch() {
    ApiService.sharedInstance.fetchGames(from:  contentURL, completion: { (content: [[contentModel]]) in
        self.content = content
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

**API-Services:**

Set the Url:

```
  func fetchGames(from url: String, completion: @escaping ([contentModel]) -> ()) {
    fetchFeedForUrlString(urlString: "\(BaseUrl)/getgames/\(url)", completion: completion)
  }
```

Fetch function:

```
 func fetchFeedForUrlString<T: Decodable>(urlString: String, completion: @escaping (T) -> ()) 
 {
        let url = URL(string: urlString)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in


        guard let data = data else {
            return
        }

        do {
            let json = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(json)
            }

        } catch let jsonError {
            print(jsonError)
        }

    }

    task.resume()
}
```

I think what I could do is make many of these fetchGames functions, but I think that would be a bad practice.
I've also read about DispatchGroup but I'm not really sure how I can implement these into my program.

Does somebody know how I can handle multiple API-calls in a good practice?

Comment: I think, API call for each cell is not a best practice, I would suggest to use a single api with pagination enabled. Fetch first few country games data and then load more on scroll using pagination

Comment: @Catherine Thank you for the answer. I have searched a little bit and found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53438239/swift-4-tableview-api-pagination but unfortunately it uses a link to the next page from the api. As I have seen, my API request doesnt provide some kind of link. Is this what you meant or am I wrong ?